# Click só funciona no segundo click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

Ao clicar no card ele deveria aumentar de tamanho e adicionar mais um texto, até esta funcionando porém estou tendo que clicar duas vezes pra abrir e queria que funcionasse com apenas um click.

Código html:

```
    <section class="contentPromos">
            <div class="promoItemAlimento .card-ativo1">
                <h3>Plano Alimentar individualizado</h3>
                <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos.  </p>
                <div class="promoItemAlimento-naoativo">
                    <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos.  </p><br><br>
                    <a class="contentPromos-btn" href="#" type="submit" onclick="vai()">EU QUERO RESULTADOS</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Código jquery:

```
$('.promoItemAlimento').on('click', function() {
        if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
            //do your stuff here if the button is not clicked
            $(this).removeClass('card-ativo1');
            $( ".promoItemAlimento-naoativo" ).css( "display", "none" );
            $(this).data('clicked', true);            
        } else {
            //do your stuff here if the button is clicked
            $(this).toggleClass('card-ativo1');
            $( ".promoItemAlimento-naoativo" ).css( "display", "block" );

        }
        };
```

Codigo css:

```
.promoItemAlimento {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 390px;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.promoItemAlimento {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #D278F1;
    
}

.promoItemAlimento-naoativo {
    display: none;
}

.card-ativo1{
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, reduza seu exemplo a um [mcve]

Comment: `<div class="promoItemAlimento .card-ativo1">` pq tem um ponto no nome da classe? além disso, já fez *debug* para ver onde entra no `if` a primeira vez?

Comment: @RicardoPontual realmente, removi o .card-ativo1 do html, mas o click continua funcionando apenas após o segundo click. E fiz sim os testes mas nao estou conseguindo identificar o motivo de não funcionar

Answer (score -3):

Pela lógica, seus códigos HTML, javascript e CSS precisam de alguns ajustes:

```html
<section class="contentPromos">
    <div class="promoItemAlimento card-ativo1">
        <h3>Plano Alimentar individualizado</h3>
        <p>Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos.  </p>
        <!-- Nome da classe alterada e uma nova classe adicionada -->
        <div class="promoItemAlimentoB naoativo">
            <p>X Tenha consultas mensais com a nutricionista para montar planos alimentares de acordo com suas necessidades, preferências e objetivos.  </p><br><br>
            <a class="contentPromos-btn" href="#" type="submit" onclick="vai()">EU QUERO RESULTADOS</a>
        </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```js
$('.promoItemAlimento').on('click', function() {
  //apenas duas funções toggle são necessárias
  $(this).toggleClass('card-ativo1');
  $(this).children('.promoItemAlimentoB').toggleClass('ativo naoativo');
})
```

CSS:

```css
.promoItemAlimento {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 390px;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.promoItemAlimento {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #D278F1;
    
}
/*Definida classe naoativo*/
.naoativo {
    display: none;
}
/*Definida classe ativo*/
.ativo {
    display: block;
}

.card-ativo1{
    height: 600px;
}
```